# Count elements in array in C

Tags: c

I can't figure out how to found size of array here is what i did

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define DEBUG 1



static void print_array(int arr[]);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int str_numbers[5] = {1,4,8,2,9};

    print_array(str_numbers);
}


static void print_array(int arr[])
{
    int total = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Total %d", total);
#endif
}
```

Result ot total is 2 instead 5. What I miss ?

Comment: The correct answer should be 5, not 4.

Comment: Why did you expect the result to be 4? I count 5 elements in `str_numbers`.

Comment: Anyway, why the result is 2 ?

Comment: How do you know it is 2?

Comment: I'm getting 5. Verify your printing function.

Comment: Your code [running at ideone](http://ideone.com/anDMa) correctly reports the count as 5. How are you checking the "result of total"?

Comment: `int arr[]` as a function parameter is equivalent to `int* arr`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wild guess: you aren't showing your code but you are in fact doing this for the parameter of a function in a 64 bit implementation with 32 bits int. sizeof(array) is the size of the array, sizeof(pointer) is the size of the pointer, not the size of the array to which the pointer may point.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int* str_numbers)
{
    int total = sizeof(str_numbers)/sizeof(str_numbers[0]);
    printf("In f: %d\n", total);
}

int main ()
{
    int str_numbers[5] = {1,4,8,2,9};
    int total = sizeof(str_numbers)/sizeof(str_numbers[0]);
    printf ("In main: %d\n", total);
    f(str_numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
In main: 5
In f: 2
```

and it is what I expect on such implementation.

Edit: Using a syntax like `print_array(int arr[])` doesn't change the fact that arr is a pointer.  There could be a way in C99 to say it is an array, but I don't remember it and VLA have been made optional in C11, to put the standard in agreement with the practice.

Comment: Psychic debugging!  Impressive reasoning, @AProgrammer.

Comment: @user1089415 then this answer is indeed correct.  When an array is passed to a function, it is "downgraded" to a pointer.

Comment: Even in C99, arrays are not first class citizens, and the parameters will be pointers, not arrays. It's a shame VLA's are optional in C11, because they were amazing syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you manage to get 2, and why do you expect to see 4. There are 5 (five) elements in your array, thus getting array length and dividing it by the size of a single element yields five:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int str_numbers[5] = {1,4,8,2,9};
    int total = sizeof(str_numbers)/sizeof(str_numbers[0]);
    printf ("%d\n", total);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -o test ./test.c 
$ ./test 
5
$
```

If you don't get the same result, you have an error in the code you are not showing. For example, you are printing it wrong. There are millions of ways to screw things up. Could be anything.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define sizeTab 5
   int f(int tab[], int sizetab)
{
    int total=0, i;
    for(i=0; i<sizetab-1; i++){
        total = sizeof(tab+i) + total;
    }

    return total;
    //free(total);
}

int main ()
{
int total = 0;
    int str_numbers[] = {1,4,8,2,9};

    int total=0, i;
    for(i=0; i<sizeTab-1; i++){
        total = sizeof(tab+i) + total;
    }
    printf ("In main: %d\n", total);
    //free(total);
    printf("f: %d\n", f(str_numbers, sizeTab));
    return 0;
}
```